# multiple status buttons - background-color

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

On the order page, there is 3 buttons

[New Order] [Processing] [Completed]

If I click on the processing button - the background of the button should change. It will also update the order status to the database.

[New Order] button will have green background by default. If I click on the  [Processing] button, the background-color will turn into green.  [New Order] will no longer have a background-color.

What the best way dealing with this using Jquery Ajax?

Comment: Any chance of you getting something up on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and [get/post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) functions....

HTML:

```
<button class="button">New Order</button>
<button class="button">Processing</button>
<button class="button">Completed</button>
```

CSS:

```
button.button {
    background-color:#fff;
    border:thin solid #000;
}
button.button:first-child {
 background-color:green;   
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button.button").click(function() {
      $("button.button").css("background-color","#fff");
      $(this).css("background-color", "green");
        $.post("updateOrder.php", {orderStatus: $(this).text()}, function(data) {
           //database updated completion logic here 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I have managed to get it to work thank you. When I refresh the page, the background color no longer there. How to deal with this?

Comment: @user622378 you could handle page refresh with jQuery's `get` function. Each time the page is loaded, load the page state from the server and style buttons accordingly.

Comment: is this ok? It work though..     if ($("#statusButtons").length > 0) {
        var orderid = $("#orderid").val();
        $.get("/admin/order/status", {
            orderid: orderid
        }, function(data) {
              $("#statusButtons .adminButton#" + data).css("background-color","green");
        });

Answer (score 1):

Just do what you described...
I'll start you up. I'm not feeling like doing all your work! :D

in the html

```
<input id="processing" type="button" />
<input id="newOrder" type="button" />
```

in a script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#newOrder').click(function(){
    $(this).css([changeBg]);
    $.ajax({
      url: "[pageToHandleUpdate]",
      data: "[update DB data]",
      success: function(){ //this is what I do after finishing the ajax call...
        $(this).css([change the style]);
        $('#newOrder').css([changeBg]);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

The `[...]` are incomplete.